# JBOSS 7.1.1 Monitoring From check_jmx

Tags: jboss7.x, monitoring, jboss6.x, nagios

I want to monitor JBOSS 7.1.1 version of server with check_jmx plugin which will greps the MBeans details. I want to know

How to connect with check_jmx plugin to the JBoss 7.1.1 version ?
What is the url do i need to give as an argument to check_jmx ?